# Prove that $\Gamma_{abc}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_bg_{ac} + \partial_cg_{ab}-\partial_ag_{bc}\right)$

Tags: solution-verification, rotations, general-relativity, permutation-cycles, index-notation

I am tasked with the following problem

> Use the equation
> $$\nabla_ag_{bc}=\partial_ag_{bc}-\Gamma_{cba}-\Gamma_{bca}=0\tag{1}$$
> where $$\Gamma_{abc}=g_{ad}\Gamma^d_{bc}\tag{A}$$
> and the (no torsion) condition
> $$\Gamma_{abc}=\Gamma_{acb}\tag{i}$$
> to show that
> $$\Gamma_{abc}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_bg_{ac} + \partial_cg_{ab}-\partial_ag_{bc}\right)\tag{B}$$

To begin, I will cycle the indices in eqn. $(1)$ so that,

$$\nabla_bg _{ca}=\partial_bg_{ca}-\Gamma_{bac}-\Gamma_{cab}=0\tag{2}$$ and cycle again to obtain
$$\nabla_c g_{ab}=\partial_cg_{ab}-\Gamma_{acb}-\Gamma_{abc}=0\tag{3}$$
Now, subtracting eqns. $(2)$ and $(3)$ from eqn. $(1)$ yields
$$\partial_a g_{bc}-\partial_b g_{ca}-\partial_c g_{ab}-\Gamma_{cba}-\Gamma_{bca}+\Gamma_{bac}+\Gamma_{cab} + \Gamma_{acb}+\Gamma_{abc}=0$$
and rearranging gives
$$\partial_a g_{bc}-\partial_b g_{ca}-\partial_c g_{ab}=\Gamma_{cba}+\Gamma_{bca}-\Gamma_{bac}-\Gamma_{cab} - \Gamma_{acb}-\Gamma_{abc}$$
Also, cycling the indices in $(\mathrm{i})$ (no torsion condition), leads to two more equations along with the original equation:
$$\Gamma_{abc}=\Gamma_{acb}\tag{i}$$
$$\Gamma_{bca}=\Gamma_{cba}\tag{j}$$
$$\Gamma_{cab}=\Gamma_{bac}\tag{k}$$

Now substituting $(\mathrm{i})$, $(\mathrm{j})$ and $(\mathrm{k})$ into the expression above,

$$\partial_a g_{bc}-\partial_b g_{ca}-\partial_c g_{ab}=\Gamma_{bca}+\Gamma_{bca}-\Gamma_{cab}-\Gamma_{cab} - \Gamma_{abc}-\Gamma_{abc}$$
simplifying and rearranging gives
$$\partial_a g_{bc}-\partial_b g_{ca}-\partial_c g_{ab}=2\Gamma_{bca}-2\Gamma_{cab} - 2\Gamma_{abc}$$
Rearranging,
$$\Gamma_{bca}  - \Gamma_{cab} - \Gamma_{abc} = \frac12 \left(\partial_c g_{ab} +\partial_b g_{ca}-\partial_a g_{bc}\right)$$

But this is not the same equation as $(\mathrm{B})$.

---

Now I will typeset the authors solution:

> $$\nabla_ag_{bc}=\partial_ag_{bc}-\Gamma_{cba}-\Gamma_{bca}$$
> Cycling the indices:
> $$\nabla_bg _{ca}=\partial_bg_{ca}-\Gamma_{\color{red}{acb}}-\Gamma_{abc}\tag{4}$$
> $$\nabla_c g_{ab}=\partial_cg_{ab}-\Gamma_{\color{red}{bac}}-\Gamma_{cab}\tag{5}$$
> Subtracting these two equations from the original equation gives
> $$\partial_a g_{bc}-\partial_b g_{ca}-\partial_c g_{ab}$$
> $$=\Gamma_{cba}+\Gamma_{bca}-\Gamma_{acb}-\Gamma_{cab}-\Gamma_{bac}-\Gamma_{abc}\stackrel{\color{red}{?}}{=}-2\Gamma_{abc},$$ using the zero torsion condition. Hence the result.

1. I can't understand the author's solution for two reasons, I marked both in red in the quote above but here is why: I think the index order in eqns $(4)$ and $(5)$ are incorrect; I think the correct expressions should be $(2)$ and $(3)$.
2. Moreover, I would like to see what justifies the final equality in the author's solution quote, which can only be the case if the first four connection terms sum to zero.

---

### Remark:

I have typed the words "cycling the indices" a lot in this question, but I didn't make it completely clear what I was doing. I am *not* swapping two of the three indices, instead, I am literally rotating the order of all $3$ indices. For example, if starting with say $bac$ I can obtain from it $ acb\to cba$ then one more rotation leads back to the starting point, $bac$. It is like going around a clock diagram in the counter-clockwise sense (the clockwise sense works equally well also):

[image: Cyclic permutations]

Above the 'clockwise sense' is depicted by the upper version of the diagram and the 'counter-clockwise sense' is the lower part of the diagram.

---

One thing that puzzles me more than anything else is that answers and comments indicate that the solution is wrong (or has typos), so I have taken a screenshot of the author's question and solution for the sake of completeness:

Here is the question:

> [image]

and here is the corresponding solution:

> [image: Levi-Civita connection solution]

Comment: I thought you were confused on what type of permutations we could do on the indices and hence wrote the answer. If you want a good reference for this, check out Pavel Grinfeld's Tensor calculus book. If I recall correctly, this was an exercise with hints given on how to find the final eqtn

Comment: I don't understand one point tho, suppose you are convinced that the author has made a mistake, why did you put it again in the post? Isn't you real question how to write the Christoffels in terms of the metric tensor derivatives?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Christoffel symbols and metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2105182/christoffel-symbols-and-metric)

Comment: I think the question is totally fine as is. It shows effort and is clear. It just turned out that the underlying problem is to understand the necessary index gymnastics, that needs to be done. That is not easy if you are just learning all that stuff. So, always okay to ask.

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai Hi, you were basically right, my confusion was on the types of permutations that are allowed. Why did you delete your answer? I was in the middle of reading it. Put simply, I am confused by everything I marked in red in the author's solution.

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai With regards to that link you posted suggesting that it may answer my question here, well it doesn't,  that question and my question are different.

Comment: Your comment made me feel that perhaps I was repeating information that you had understood already. Then when I found Alex's answer, I thought your question would have been answered directly by it. Hence, I deleted my answer. I suppose I misunderstood you. Btw, could you elaborate on how your question is different from that previous question. There ultimately the equation is derived and some conceptual discussion is done as well

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai Hi yes, so this question is different to the one you gave a link to as this one involves cycling and renaming the indices for the Levi-Civita connection, the linked answers to that question do not address this. In fact, the question linked is not even about the Levi-Civita connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be something wrong with the cyclic renaming of indices in (2) and (3) as well as in (4) and (5). The main thing to keep in mind is that you cannot just cycle indices, but you must cyclically *rename* indices.

If you start with the correct equation:

$$\nabla_ag_{bc}=\partial_ag_{bc}-\Gamma_{cba}-\Gamma_{bca}$$

and you cyclically rename the indices on the lhs using $abc \to bca$ you have to do the same cyclic *renaming* on the rhs. You cannot just cycle indices $cba \to bac$ using the same permutation, but $cba$ becomes $acb$. So the correct expressions are:

$$ \nabla_bg_{ca}=\partial_bg_{ca}-\Gamma_{cab}-\Gamma_{acb}=0\tag{6} $$
$$ \nabla_cg_{ab}=\partial_cg_{ab}-\Gamma_{abc}-\Gamma_{bac}=0\tag{7} $$

You can also check this by keeping in mind that these are actually just dummy indices, placeholders for the multiplication with vector fields. If you check (1), you see that the index of the deriviative ($a$) always appears as the last index in the Christoffel symbols. If your derivative index is $b$ or $c$ it must also be the case that $b$ or $c$ are the last indices in the Christoffel symbols.

The same problem arises in equations (i), (j), and (k). Think about what
$$\Gamma_{abc}=\Gamma_{acb}\tag{i}$$
actually means. It means that the Christoffel symbols are symmetric in the last two indices. So if you *rename* the indices in (i) you get
$$\Gamma_{bca}=\Gamma_{bac}\tag{l}$$
$$\Gamma_{cab}=\Gamma_{cba}\tag{m}$$

If you put everything together now:
$$\partial_a g_{bc}-\partial_b g_{ca}-\partial_c g_{ab}=\Gamma_{cba}+\Gamma_{bca}-\Gamma_{cab}-\Gamma_{acb} - \Gamma_{abc}-\Gamma_{bac}$$
Using (l) and (m) yields:
$$\partial_a g_{bc}-\partial_b g_{ca}-\partial_c g_{ab}=-\Gamma_{acb} - \Gamma_{abc}$$
Finally, using (i):
$$\partial_a g_{bc}-\partial_b g_{ca}-\partial_c g_{ab}=-2\Gamma_{abc}$$

Comment: If I'm understanding what you mean by 'renaming indices' correctly, then to get from $(6)$ to $(7)$ you are using the 'mapping' $b\to c,\,c\to a, \,a\to b$, which gives the right indices for the Christoffel symbols in eqn. $(7)$. But this logic doesn't work to get from eqn. $(1)$ to $(6)$ though, where the mapping is $a\to b,\,b\to c, \,c\to a$, which gives $\nabla_bg_{ca}=\partial_bg_{ca}-\Gamma_{acb}-\Gamma_{cab}=0$. Are you sure that equation $(6)$ is clear of typos? I understand the rest (I think), just that bit.

Comment: I just realized that both my expression in the comment above and your equation $(6)$ are the same but with the last two (Christoffel) terms interchanged, this threw me off a bit, but I think I realize now why you swapped them. It was to emphasize what you said about the last index on the final Christoffel symbol being the same as the partial derivative index right?

Comment: Right, the equation you gave and (6) are the same. Just the Christoffel symbols swapped. The actual reason, I arrived at that specific order of the Christoffel symbols is, that I rewrote the original expression as $g_{bc;a} = g_{bc,a} - 2\Gamma_{(bc)a}$. For me that makes renaming the indices much easier. But I thought including it in the answer might be more confusing than helpful.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and for taking the time to explain the logic carefully. I am very curious why the author's solution is incorrect. So I have posted (as embedded images) the author's question and solution in my post. Could you please take a look at the end of my edited post to see if there really are typos in those quotes? I'm confused as the chance of there being a typo in a past exam question (which is what this is) and the corresponding solution is *extremely* rare.

Comment: The solution you posted in your edit is correct. I can't find any typos. It seems there were just typos/errors, when you included the solution in your original question in eqns (4) and (5).

Comment: Thank you for checking this, I took screenshots just to make sure I didn't mistype any of the author's solution, especially equations $(4)$ and $(5)$.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to limit yourself to circular arrangement. The $a,b,c$ are just indices, they hold no significant. You can have any sort of derangement as long as you swap on both side correctly.

To understand this, suppose you actually put a value of the indices say $(a,b,c)=(1,1,1)$, then even if you had marked the indices by $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ in the final evaluation you'd get the same thing. Get what I mean?

Edit:
We have,

> $$\nabla_ag_{bc}=\partial_ag_{bc}-\Gamma_{cba}-\Gamma_{bca}=0\tag{1}$$
> and want the following:
> $$\nabla_bg _{ca}=\partial_bg_{ca}-\Gamma_{\color{red}{acb}}-\Gamma_{abc}\tag{4}$$

We have to replace $(a,b,c)$ with $(b,c,a)$ , so all the $a$ become $b$ , all the $b$ become $c$ and all the $c$ become a. I get by direct calculation:

$$ \nabla_{b} g_{ca} = \partial_b g_{ca}- \Gamma_{acb}-\Gamma_{cab} \tag{5}$$

Seems so there is some sort of mistake in eqtn 4.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you write "as long as you swap on both side correctly", but in the author's solution he/she does *not* swap them on both sides correctly, this is why I indicated it with the red color in equations $(4)$ and $(5)$. I have swapped the indices correctly in $(2)$ as $\Gamma_{cba}\to \Gamma_{bac}$ and $(3)$ as $\Gamma_{bac}\to \Gamma_{acb}$. So no, sorry I don't get what you mean.

Comment: Seems so that four is wrong @FutureCop

Comment: damn always getting downvoted with no explanation ;-;

Comment: Thanks for reinstating your answer, and yeah, I agree with you; nothing worse than anonymous downvotes. It certainly seems that the author's solution is erroneous.